# Why browser shows the pdf from dompdf correctly, but when I print it it have more margin?

Tags: css, pdf, dompdf

I have a PDF generated with dompdf. This pdf is correct when the browser shows it. It has a header and a fotter perfectly positioned, but when I go to print this pdf, the preview view show more top, and bottom margin in the header and fotter, and also once it is printed.

I used both of this CSS properties to define margin 0:

```
@page { margin: 0px; }
body { margin: 0px; }
```

I do not understand if maybe any other style, or something that I miss is generating this difference between what the screen display and what I print.

Can anyone help me?

Thanks.

Comment: This is probably a PDF viewer setting. Some viewers have a setting to shrink a PDF to the printable area. Which viewer are you using?

Comment: Thanks for your answer BrianS. I am viewing the pdf with the default pdf viewer from macbook pro. I also tried with PDF reader from windows 8.
The fact is that before downloading the file I display this as a view on the browser and it have the same margins that shows the pdf reader.  Then I click on donwload as PDF and shos correctly the pdf, but when I go to the printer all margins are different...

Comment: This is usually a setting in the print options for the PDF viewer. In OSX you would open the print dialog, click the "Show Details" button, then set the scaling factor ([ref](https://support.apple.com/kb/ph18605?locale=en_US)). In Windows 8 the process would be similar (I didn't find an official page, but see [here](http://www.brighthub.com/computing/windows-platform/articles/69895.aspx).

Comment: Any solution? I have the same problem here...
https://imgur.com/a/K3RNq2y

Comment: I just solved it. I just needed to set the property ->setPaper('A4', 'portrait')